# RxJs Marble Test Fails When Using Observable.fromPromise

Tags: unit-testing, rxjs5, redux-observable

I have been attempting to write an RxJS marble test for a simple redux-observable epic but cannot get it to pass.  It appears that using fromPromise in the observable chain under test does not emit the items per the expected marble sequence when flush is called on the testScheduler.

Providing a sample of the test.  If I replace Observable.fromPromise to Observable.of the test will pass.

Any insight is appreciated. RxJS 5 / redux-observable 0.18

```
...
const MY_ACTION = 'MY_ACTION';

const myAction = () => ({
  type: MY_ACTION,
  payload: {test: 'testval'},
});

const epic = action$ =>
  action$.ofType(MY_ACTION).switchMap(() =>
    Observable.concat(
      Observable.of({type: 'test1'}),
      Observable.fromPromise(Promise.resolve({type: 'test2'})),
    )
  );

it('it should work', () => {
  const deepEquals = (actual, expected) => {
    expect(actual).to.deep.equal(expected);
  };

  const createTestScheduler = () =>
    new TestScheduler(deepEquals);

  const marbles1 = '-a-';
  const marbles2 = '-(bc)-';
  const values = {
    a: myAction(),
    b: {type: 'test1'},
    c: {type: 'test2'},
  };

  const ts = createTestScheduler();
  const source = ActionsObservable.from(
    ts.createColdObservable(marbles1, values)
  );
  const actual = epic(source);


  ts.expectObservable(actual);

  ts.expectObservable(actual).toBe(marbles2, values);
  ts.flush();
});
...
```

Comment: The problem is that `Promise.resolve` is asynchronous, but `flush` requires the composed observables to be synchronous or to use the test scheduler's concept of virtual time.

Comment: Thanks for the reply,  is there anywhere in the RxJS documentation I can review to learn about this constraint?

Comment: Answered my own question - see https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/pull/745 and https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/701 - appears not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the documentation under the 'Known issues' section: https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/testing/marble-testing

You can use the `from` operator to wrap a promise like so:

```
const myAsyncCode = () => from(Promise.resolve('something'));

it('has async code', (done) => {
  myAsyncCode().subscribe((d) => {
    assertEqual(d, 'something');
    done();
  });
});
```